# iphone core data: three tier Entity relationship confusion

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity-relationship

Re the Core Data table below.  I want to associate the "Color" entity with the "detailsColor" attribute (in the Details entity).  The idea is that there are (in this case) three Colors applicable to detailsColor.

I would have thought the "Relationships" in Color would apply to the "detailsColor" attribute as these colors only apply there.  I cannot seem to connect the two though.  I can only create a relationship with the entire Details entity.  Is this correct?  Suggestions appreciated.

[image: Core Data]

Answer (score 0):

A relation connects entities, so it doesn't make sense to say that "colorDetails" applies "to the entire Details entity". Your set up looks okay to me.

Comment: Thanks edsko.  One related question.  I display "Details" in a TableView, and "detailsColor" is always objectAtIndex:0.  When the user wants to update the colors, I can't work out what object to pass to the next NIB that allows the user to (a) select any combination of "consistent," "inconsistent," or "multiColored" and (b) save into Color attributes.  I tried {    controller.details = [details valueForKey:@"detailsColor"]; } but this seems to pass the values and not the object.  Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I think I found the answer {controller.details = details;}.  I just needed to passed the whole object and not a valueForKey.  Who knew..